# What does it mean lattice softening and stiffening?

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Which kind of proceedings does it pretend? And why it is applied to examine high temperature superconductivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain materials such as e.g. cuprates or iron-based superconductors exhibit quantum phase transitions characterised by "lattice softening", which means that one or more of the elastic constants are greatly reduced as you approach the 2nd-order phase transition line. This phenomenon is currently under very active investigation with the study of the so-called *nematic* phase of cuprates and FeSC which phase transition induces such lattice softening.

You can see extended discussion on the topic [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6925) or [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04861).